# (hoangnm/react-native-week-view) How can Add 30 mint time difference. react native week view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[image]

How to add 30 mints time differences between one hours .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/hoangnm/react-native-week-view#full-api), use `timeStep` prop.

```
import WeekView from 'react-native-week-view';

const MyComponent = () => (
  <WeekView
    events={myEvents}
    selectedDate={new Date(2021, 3, 15)}
    numberOfDays={7}
    timeStep={30}
  />
);
```

Comment: 2023 update: documentation was moved: https://hoangnm.github.io/react-native-week-view/full-api/week-view-props#timestep